# Регулярное выражение для PHP

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Помогите с регуляркой для PHP.
Необходимо находить строки, соответствующие следующему условию: состоит из английских букв разного регистра, но последние две буквы в верхнем.

Например:

```
NewFolDerEN - подходит
asdASFKD - подходит
qwpoeiDFa - не подходит
```

Comment: Ну хоть бы свой, пусть неправильный, вариант написали

Comment: `[a-zA-Z]*[A-Z]{2}$`

Comment: наверное, надо начало строки поставить `^[a-zA-Z]*[A-Z]{2}$`, а то `123AB` сгодится

Answer (score 1):

Вариант из комментариев под вопросом действительно сгодится:

```
^[a-zA-Z]*[A-Z]{2}$
```